# Is it true that $\lim_{x\to\ 0} f(x)=A$ implies $\lim_{\frac{x}{2}\to\ 0} f(x)=A$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Is this theorem true?

$$\lim_{x\to\ 0} f(x)=A$$
$$\implies \lim_{\frac{x}{2}\to\ 0} f(x)=A$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE, what have you tried?

Comment: I came across this theorem in a proof. Is the theorem true?

Comment: Can you prove it?

Comment: I will prove it once I know it is true... Is it really true?

Comment: Yes, now give it a shot, try answering your own question! $\textbf{Hint:}$ Use the definition of a limit [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfLimit.aspx)

Comment: Fix $\epsilon>0$.

Then for some $\delta>0$

$\hspace{0.5in}0 < \left| {x} \right| < \delta
\implies\left| {f\left( x \right) - A} \right| < \varepsilon \hspace{0.5in}$

Now what??? please help

Comment: First you will need to provide a definition for something of the form $$\lim_{\varphi(t)\to 0} f(t)$$  Since this is not a special case of the usual definitions, you should provide your own definition of what it means in $\varepsilon \delta$ form.

Comment: Use the fact that in your new definition of limit you get $0<\frac{1}{2}\vert x \vert < \delta \Rightarrow 0<\vert x \vert < 2 \delta$

Comment: And use this to show your resultant is less than $2\epsilon$ which is enough. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that

$$0<\vert x \vert < \delta \Rightarrow \vert f(x)-A \vert<\epsilon$$

Then in the new one, we obtain

$$0< \frac{1}{2}\vert x \vert < \delta \Rightarrow 0< \vert x \vert < 2 \delta$$

This implies

$$\vert f(x) - A \vert < 2 \epsilon$$

but $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily chosen and the limit is still $A$ as desired.

Comment: _Why_ does $|f(x)-A|<2\epsilon$ follow at the end??????????? (Note that for example  knowing that $|x|<c\delta$ does _not_ imply $|f(x)-A|<c\epsilon$ in general.)

Comment: @Hossien Sahebjame: I agree with David C. Ullrich. Moreover, if I'm not wrong, from $|x|<2\delta$ you cannot deduce $|f(x)-A|<\epsilon$ either because the estimation $|f(x)-A|<\epsilon$ of the limit hypothesis is valid only if $|x|<\delta$; so when $|x|<2\delta$ you cannot deduce anything in general, since it could be $\delta \le |x|<2\delta$. You can only deduce the following: since $|x|/2<|x|$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, from the hypothesis you can only deduce that $|f(x/2)-A|<\epsilon$. But this doesn't prove the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x/2=t$, hence $x=2t$; from $x/2=t$, when $x/2 \to 0$ it is $t \to 0$. Thus:
$$\lim_{x/2 \to 0} f(x)=\lim_{t \to 0} f(2t)$$
Let $2t=u$; from $2t=u$, when $t \to 0$ it is $u \to 0$. Thus:
$$\lim_{t \to 0} f(2t)=\lim_{u \to 0} f(u)$$
By hypothesis the latter limit is equal to $A$, hence $\lim_{x/2 \to 0} f(x)=A$ as well.